# If a theory has a model, does a theory have to be consistent?

Tags: logic, model-theory

This may be a too obvious question, but then in completeness theorem, direction is only in one direction: if a theory is consistent, then it has a model. Can we make it stronger and say that a theory has a model if and only if a theory is consistent?

Comment: "A consistent theory has a model" is also known as Henkin's Theorem, or The Henkin Theorem.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I've never heard it called that - just "the completeness theorem" (of which it's an immediate corollary). Is it referred to separately as such?

Comment: @NoahSchweber. I just recall that name from  the hand-written lecture notes from a course in Model Theory, decades ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes; the other half you're asking about is the [soundness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness), which states that if $T$ proves $\varphi$ then $\varphi$ is true in every model of $T$. In particular, if $T$ proves $\perp$ then $T$ has no model, and so by the contrapositive any satisfiable theory is consistent.

The proof of the soundness theorem is much simpler than that of the completeness theorem: we just show that each of the clauses of our proof system match up appropriately with the definition of satisfaction.

Comment: Does it hold for second order languages with "all"-qualifiers?